# :focus in IE not working

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, focus

I've created a site with CSS that requires the :focus pseudo class. I change the 'filter' and 'background-image' effects when a textbox is selected (i.e. has focus). This works in Chrome/FF, but doesn't seem to work in IE8 (and, presumable, previous versions if IE). I tried to look for answers, and have tried to use :active - but that doesn't work. Is there a way of changing attributes such as 'filter' using psuedo-classes? Failing that, can I do it in JS with the OnClick event?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use the "onclick" event to handle "onfocus". Remember, users can use the keyboard on your website so intercepting click events isn't very useful. If you go the JavaScript route, use the "focus" and "blur" events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-classes on IE: [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html)

> Most modern browsers support the
>   :hover selector for any html element.
>   This is cool, because it enables you
>   to, for instance, apply a mouseover
>   effect to table rows  using only
>   CSS. IE however, has an erratic
>   support for :hover at best, depending
>   on the particular version your visitor
>   is using.
>
> Whatever:hover is a small script that
>   automatically patches :hover, :active
>   and :focus for IE6, IE7 and IE8
>   quirks, letting you use them like you
>   would in any other browser. Version 3
>   introduces ajax support, meaning that
>   any html that gets inserted into the
>   document via javascript will also
>   trigger :hover, :active and :focus
>   styles in IE.

http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html